# Upload file with Mechanize for Ruby

Tags: ruby, mechanize

File upload does not work using:

```
form.file_upload_with(:name => 'image[1]').file_name = '/tmp/image.jpg'
form.submit
```

This is an out-of-date example: https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/master/examples/flickr_upload.rb

I tried this on two different sites.

I'm using Mechanize 2.6.0.

Comment: "....file_name = '/tmp/image.jpg'" return string with file name; "form.submit" return page after submit, page so that I did not choose the file

Answer (score 9):

Slightly off-topic, but another way to upload files with Mechanize I found useful, particularly if you don't have a HTML form handy, is to just use `Mechanize.post` with a `File` instance:

```
a = Mechanize.new
a.post(url, {
    "file1" => File.new("/tmp/image.jpg")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
file = File.join( APP_ROOT, 'tmp', 'image.jpg')
form.file_uploads.first.file_name = file
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
form_with(:method => /POST/) do |form|
    form.file_uploads.first.file_name = '/tmp/image.jpg'
end.submit
```

Comment: did not help,
this is equivalent